# repeated two-way ANOVA on multiple columns sorted per factor level in r

Tags: r, function, automation, anova, summary

I want see with a two-way ANOVA for each of the 10 environmental variables ( `height`,  `iwdo`, `rdos`, etc.. until `no2`) differences among `period` and `site`.
This, in three different indipendent watersheds grouped in  `stream`.

For each `stream` I need to check the normality with `shapiro.test` and the homoscedasticity with `leveneTest`. After I run the model `aov(nest_database[nest_database=="stream name (i.e. smeltaite)",]environmental variable (i.e.iwdo)~period*site)`.

So, is there a formula that can automatize such process for the three `stream` and at the same time being reproduced on each column of environmental variables giving me a summary for `shapiro.test`, `leveneTest` and `aov` results respectively?

down below the `head` of my dataset

```
nest_data<-structure(list(stream = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = 
c("blendziava", 
"smeltaite", "sventoji"), class = "factor"), period = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("February", "March", "April", 
"May"), class = c("ordered", "factor")), site = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("N", "NN"), class = "factor"), 
   stake = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C"), class = c("low", 
   "medium", "low", "low", "low", "high"), height = c(0, 10, 
   0, 3.5, 0, 15), iwdo = c(13, 8.37, 10.8, 3.3, 11, 5.3), rdos = c(89.041095890411, 
   57.3287671232877, 73.972602739726, 22.6027397260274, 75.3424657534247, 
   36.3013698630137), iwc = c(359, 375, 357, 340, 360, 357), 
   dwc = c(2, 14, 4, 21, 1, 4), iwt = c(2.2, 2.1, 2.3, 2.3, 
   2.6, 2.3), dt = c(0, 0.1, 0.0999999999999996, 0.0999999999999996, 
   0.4, 0.0999999999999996), no3 = c(0.8104551, 0.6300294, 1.1296698, 
   1.2962166, 0.963123, 1.240701), nh4 = c(0.2187052, 0.1457344, 
   0.186718, 0.2177056, 0.2297008, 0.2187052), no2 = c(0.0133336, 
   0.0100408, 0.0116872, 0.0083944, 0.0127848, 0.009492)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

So far I'm using the code:

```
nest_data %>% 
 split(.$stream) %>% 
 purrr::map(.,function(x){
     aov(iwdo ~ period*site, data = x) %>%
         tidy(.)
 }) -> results
```

df <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind,results))

that allows me to perform the test on the three `stream` but only on one column.
I presume that I should use a `for` cycle but not sure where to put inside the function

Thanks in advance and hope I was clear since this is my first question here!

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider generalizing all your steps in a defined method. Then call method iteratively which base R methods of `by` and `sapply` can help. Use `reformulate` to adjust formula. Please fill in each ellipsis (`...`).

```r
env_vars <- c("height", "iwdo", "rdos", ..., "no2")

proc_model <- function(sub_df) {
    # NAMED LIST OF ENVIRONMENT VARS MODEL AND TESTS
    sapply(env_vars, function(env) {
        model <- aov(reformulate("period*site", env), data = sub_df)
        sp <- shapiro.test(...)
        lv <- leveneTest(...)

        # NAMED LIST OF MODEL AND TESTS
        list(
            aov_result = model, shapiro_test = sp, levene_test = lv
        )
    }, simplify=FALSE)
}

# NESTED NAMED LIST BY STREAM FOR EACH ENV VAR
results_list <- by(nest_data, nest_data$stream, proc_model)
```

To access results:

```r
results_list$smeltaite$height$aov_result
results_list$smeltaite$height$shapiro_test
results_list$smeltaite$height$levene_test
```

For your original implementation:

```r
results <- nest_data %>% 
 split(.$stream) %>% 
 purrr::map(proc_model)
```

Comment: Thank you so much Parfait! I still have a doubt: when I type `results_list` I can visualize df and sum of Sq, but not P and F stat. Furthermore, using the command `results_list$smeltaite$height$aov_result`, I have `NULL` as output. How can I find the `aov_summary`?

Comment: You may need to take run anova results in `summary`: `summary(results_list$smeltaite$height$aov_result)`. I made a slight change for `sapply` to return a list which was the reason for `NULL` . See [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73514024/revisions).

Comment: Thank you so much Parfait! It works really well and smoothly ;)